# My team does not assert

Tags: java, assert, jvm-arguments, assertion

I came back to Java after some years working mostly Python and C/C++. I often worked using `assert`s among other constructions. Today it's difficult to me to mindset me not to use assertions.

```
$ java -help 2>&1 | grep -2 "\-ea"
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
```

My team does not use `-ea` under no circumstances, so I'm using constructs like:

```
assert COND;
if (! COND) {
    throw new AssertionError("COND was not true");
}
```

Where I would just put `assert COND;`.

Often like:

```
assert variable != null;
if (variable == null) {
    throw new AssertionError("variable was null");
}
```

Where I would just put `assert variable != null;`.

Do you have any comment on this or on on how can this be improved?

Comment: public void assert(boolean condition, final String message) throws AssertionError {if (!cond) throw new AssertionError(message);} call as assert(some condition, "some message");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My team does not use -ea under no circumstances

Well, then change that? Shouldn't be difficult/hurt much to add that to a test server.

> ```
> assert COND;
> if (! COND) {
>     throw new AssertionError("COND was not true");
> }
> ```

Those things are not the same. One can be turned off, the other can't.

Always-enforced validation might be used for sanitation of untrusted inputs.

Assertions on the other hand should only be used to guard against programmer errors.

Answer (score 2):

Asserts can be disabled and are therefore not guaranteed to be active at any time.  This is probably *the* reason very few people use them.

These days unit tests have taken the place of asserts as they exercise the code to see that it behaves as expected.  Additionally annotations like @Nullable help the IDE catch potential null pointers in places where they are not allowed.

I would suggest asking your team how they want checks like these to be done.  [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Verify.html) and Java 8 have useful helper methods for this.

Comment: Actually unit tests and asserts combined are pretty strong. It is dangerous to enable assertions in production if you do not test and develop with assertions enabled. However running unit tests should always enable assertions.

Comment: Assertions mean that you now have two different paths in your code.  This mean that you risk running different code than you tested (the assert code may have side effects), which may be unacceptable for political reasons.